# gatsby & graphql : filtering for a specific single image

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby, netlify, gatsby-image

I don't really understand graphql or gatsby that well but I believe all my images are loaded into graphql by putting this in my gatsby-config.js

```js
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: path.join(__dirname, `src/assets/images`),
      },
    },
```

I am then trying to query a specific image which I can do with

```js
    query MyQuery {
      allImageSharp(filter: {id: {eq: "7acfccd5-4aef-532b-8889-9d844ae2068b"}}) {
        edges {
          node {
            sizes {
              sizes
              srcSet
              src
              aspectRatio
            }
            id
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

And this returns what I want, but the id that I have to enter for this query is `7acfccd5-4aef-532b-8889-9d844ae2068b`. Is this id even going to stay the same if I put it in my code? Is there a way to set the id to something more sensical?

If I save my query to a variable `data`, it turns out that on **Netlify** `data.allImageSharp.edges[0]` is null, while locally this value will return what I need

I'm looking for the best way to query a **single** image. **Not multiple** images.
If I could set my own id's then I could query these.

---

**Update**

I found an example in the [gatsby-source-filesystem documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-filesystem/#retrieving-the-remote-file-name-and-extension), but don't really know how to add it to my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have an image with a path of `src/images/exampleImage.jpg`, you can query by the images name by querying using **file** rather than **allImageSharp**.

```
query HeaderQuery {
  exampleImage: file(
    extension: {eq: "jpg"},
    name: {eq: "exampleImage"}
  ) {
    childImageSharp {
      fluid {
        src
        srcSet
        sizes
        srcSetWebp
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

You can also replace `{extension: {eq: "jpg"}` with `{extension: {regex: "/(jpg)|(jpeg)|(png)/"}` to query files of any extension type.

Answer (score 2):

With this snippet:

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
  options: {
    name: `images`,
    path: path.join(__dirname, `src/assets/images`),
  },
},
```

Basically you are telling your GraphQL schema that will find `images` in `src/assets/images` folder so you will be able to query all the content inside this folder via GraphQL. You are specifying the source for your data.

From [gatsby-source-filesystem documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-source-filesystem/):

> The plugin creates File nodes from files. The various “transformer”
>   plugins can transform File nodes into various other types of data e.g.
>   gatsby-transformer-json transforms JSON files into JSON data nodes and
>   gatsby-transformer-remark transforms markdown files into
>   MarkdownRemark nodes from which you can query an HTML representation
>   of the markdown.

Answering your question, of course, you can filter and sort for any property or node that your image has, such as name, path, extension, etc. You may find a useful and autocompletion tool for your queries under `/___graphql` path when you run a `gatsby develop` command. This will help you to check out what parameters can be queried and filtered.

Comment: I've been using `/__graphql` I think the answer is somewhere in the gatsby-source-filesystem-documentation. I currently create nodes for markdown pages in my gatsby-node.js, but I kinda just copied and pasted the code. It looks like they have an example for jpgs, but I don't really understand it. I'm going to add it to my question

Comment: Hey so I'm not quite sure what you meant. The graphql query in my question works locally, but `data.allImagesSharp` returns an empty array when pushed to Netlify. Do you have an example? I got that crazy number `7acfccd5-4aef-532b-8889-9d844ae2068b` from graphql so I don't know how to change it

Comment: Hi again @Sam. It's a bit tricky to work with `gatsby-image`. Usually is "common" to receive an empty array in development in `___graphql` mode but the query can still work. Can you provide the full `gatsby-config.js` file?

Comment: K, it's up there

Comment: The `gatsby-node.js` provided in this question misses some configuration found in the other question and answer @Sam:

`const { fmImagesToRelative } = require('gatsby-remark-relative-images');

exports.onCreateNode = ({ node }) => {
  fmImagesToRelative(node);
};` for example

Comment: Yeah, I ended up removing that because I found that it didn't make a difference. I can add it back in but that part isn't the problem. It has something to do with the query. On the server `allImagesSharp.edges[0]` is null but locally it has what I need

Comment: Added @Sam . Thanks for the feedback!